# Identify subsequent event for repeat IDs based on dates and initial event

Tags: r, duplicates

I am trying to determine repeat IDs based on date and an initial event. Below is a sample data set

```
+----+------------+-------------------------+
| ID |    Date    | Investigation or Intake |
+----+------------+-------------------------+
|  1 | 1/1/2019   | Investigation           |
|  2 | 1/2/2019   | Investigation           |
|  3 | 1/3/2019   | Investigation           |
|  4 | 1/4/2019   | Investigation           |
|  1 | 1/2/2019   | Intake                  |
|  2 | 12/31/2018 | Intake                  |
| 3  | 1/5/2019   | Intake                  |
+----+------------+-------------------------+
```

I want to write R codes to go through IDs from 1 to 4 (IDs that have investigations) and see if they have a subsequent intake (an intake that happens at a later date than the date of investigation). So the expected output looks like this:

```
+----+------------+-------------------------+------------+
| ID |    Date    | Investigation or Intake | New Column |
+----+------------+-------------------------+------------+
|  1 | 1/1/2019   | Investigation           | Sub Intake |
|  2 | 1/2/2019   | Investigation           | None       |
|  3 | 1/3/2019   | Investigation           | Sub Intake |
|  4 | 1/4/2019   | Investigation           | None       |
|  1 | 1/2/2019   | Intake                  |            |
|  2 | 12/31/2018 | Intake                  |            |
| 3  | 1/5/2019   | Intake                  |            |
+----+------------+-------------------------+------------+
```

What will the code look like to solve this? I am guessing it will be some loop function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this using the `dplyr` package and using some `ifelse` statements create a new column as required.
Instead of using looping instead just check the next entry in the group using `lead` function.
This solution assumes that in each group you will have one "Investigation" and then 0 or more "Intake" entries that are listed afterwards.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3),
                   Date = as.Date(c("2019-01-01", "2019-01-02", "2019-1-03", "2019-01-04", "2019-01-02", "2018-12-31", "2019-1-5")),
                   Investigation_or_Intake = c("Investigation", "Investigation", "Investigation", "Investigation", "Intake", "Intake", "Intake"),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
 df %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>% # Make groups according to ID column
   mutate(newcol = ifelse(lead(Date) > Date, "Sub Intake", "None"), # Check next entry in the group to see if Date is after current
          newcol = ifelse(Investigation_or_Intake == "Investigation" & is.na(newcol), "None", newcol)) # Change "Investigation" entries with no Intake to "None"
```

This gives

```
ID Date       Investigation_or_Intake newcol    
  <dbl> <date>     <chr>                   <chr>     
1     1 2019-01-01 Investigation           Sub Intake
2     2 2019-01-02 Investigation           None      
3     3 2019-01-03 Investigation           Sub Intake
4     4 2019-01-04 Investigation           None      
5     1 2019-01-02 Intake                  NA        
6     2 2018-12-31 Intake                  NA        
7     3 2019-01-05 Intake                  NA
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your solution almost gave me what I wanted. I should have mentioned that each group can have more than one "investigation". So when I ran your code, if a person has another investigation after the first investigation, I have "sub intake" for that record. Ideally, i would like for only the investigations that have a sub intake to be labelled "sub intake", if the investigation has a subsequent "investigation" it can be ignored. Or better yet, is there a way to label "sub intake" or "sub invest" for all the investigations?

Comment: Is it possible for an investigation to have both a subsequent investigation and a subsequent intake?

Comment: Yes, an investigation can have both one or multiple subsequent investigation and one or multiple subsequent intake.